# combining a random variable and its inverse

Tags: geometric-mean

I am measuring two scientific entities, X and Y using empiric measurements. Each has its own mean and sample variance based on Nx and Ny sample measurements. 
I know from the underlying science that X is 1/Y (e.g. one variable is the inverse of the other). 
Because the sampling is empiric I don't get a result which is exactly inverse. I want to make the best estimate of the ratio between them. 
e.g. 
let X have a mean of 4 based on 30 measurements with a stdev of 3.
let Y have a mean of 0.4 based on 12 measurements with stdev of 0.5

so combining the two I should have something like X=3 and Y=1/3
But maybe it should be X=3.5 and Y=1/3.5 etc..

How do I go about finding the best ratio?

Comment: By "best ratio" are you trying to estimate a single, common underlying value $\mu$ such that the expected value of the $X_i$ is $\mu$ and the expected value of the $Y_j$ is $1/\mu$?  And by "best," how is that to be ascertained? Do you want to get as accurate as possible an estimate of $\mu$, or perhaps do you want to get as accurate as possible an estimate of $1/\mu$?  (The two will not necessarily be the same!)  And why have you tagged this question with [tag:geometric-mean]?

Comment: A confusion with harmonic mean?

Answer (score 3):

It *sounds* like you have a dataset consisting of measurements $(x_i, i=1,2,\ldots,n)$ and $(y_j, j=1,2,\ldots,m)$ (with $n=30, m=12$).  Let us posit that

1. All the measurements can be considered independent random variables.
2. There is a fixed number ("parameter") $\mu$ for which all $x_i-\mu$ have a common distribution $F$ (whose expectation is $0$, reflecting a lack of bias in those measurements) and all the $y_j - 1/\mu$ have a common distribution $G$ (also with $0$ expected value).

**One way to make some progress** is to study the error distributions $F$ and $G$.  To illustrate how this information can be used, let us consider a widely applicable model in which the distributions have identical shapes but unknown amounts of dispersion (which we will measure with the variance).  Let the variance of $F$ be $\sigma^2$ and the variance of $G$ be $\tau^2$.  Often these distributions will be approximately Normal, for instance (although many other forms of error can be modeled).

The independence assumptions imply the likelihood of the observations, $L$, is the product of their individual probability densities.  Let $\phi$ be the density for a unit variance.  When we assume Normally-distributed variation, for instance,

$$\phi(z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp({-z^2/2}).$$

Then $\phi_\sigma(x) = \phi(x/\sigma)/\sigma$ is the density of $F$ and $\phi_\tau(y)=\phi(y/\tau)/\tau$ is the density of $G$.  Accordingly,

$$L(\mu, \sigma, \tau; (x_i), (y_j)) = \prod_{i=1}^n \phi_\sigma(x_i-\mu) \prod_{j=1}^m \phi_\tau(y_j-1/\mu).$$

**We may estimate $\mu$ using the method of Maximum Likelihood:** find values of $\mu,\sigma,\tau$ that make this likelihood as large as possible.
To simplify the products, and to conform with a convention that optimization problems are usually cast as minimization problems, let us minimize the negative log likelihood

$$\eqalign{
\Lambda(\mu,\sigma,\tau) &= -\log(L(\cdots)) \\
&= -\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\log \phi\left(\frac{x_i-\mu}{\sigma}\right)  - \log \sigma \right) - \sum_{j=1}^m \left(\log \phi\left(\frac{y_j-1/\mu}{\tau}\right)  - \log \tau \right) \\
&=-n\log\sigma - m\log\tau - \sum_{i=1}^n \log \phi\left(\frac{x_i-\mu}{\sigma}\right)  - \sum_{j=1}^m\log \phi\left(\frac{y_j-1/\mu}{\tau}\right).
}$$

To continue the illustration, assume from now on that the error distributions are Normal.  We easily find that the minimum must occur when $\sigma^2$ is the variance of the $(x_i)$ and $\tau$ is the variance of the $(y_j)$:

$$\hat\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar x)^2; \quad \bar x = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i; \\
\hat\tau^2= \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m (y_i - \bar y)^2; \quad \bar y = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{j=1}^m y_j.$$

**It remains to find $\hat\mu$ for which $\Lambda(\hat\mu,\hat\sigma,\hat\tau)$ is minimum.**  This value could be any real number--there are no boundary values to check.  Since $\Lambda$ is a differentiable function of its first argument, the minimum must occur at a zero of its derivative:

$$0 = \frac{\partial}{\partial \mu}\Lambda(\mu,\cdots) = \frac{1}{ \hat\sigma }\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\phi^\prime\left(\frac{x_i-\mu}{\hat\sigma}\right)}{  \phi\left(\frac{x_i-\mu}{\hat\sigma}\right)  }  - 
\frac{1}{\mu^2 \hat\tau}\sum_{j=1}^m \frac{\phi^\prime\left(\frac{y_j-1/\mu}{\hat\tau}\right)}{ \phi\left(\frac{y_j-1/\mu}{\hat\tau}\right)  }. $$

Normal distributions are often chosen in models precisely because the function $\phi^\prime(z)/\phi(z) = -z$ is *linear*, making such equations easy to solve.  In this case the presence of $1/\mu$ complicates things a bit:

$$\frac{n}{\hat \sigma^2}\left(\bar x - \mu\right) = \frac{1}{\hat\sigma}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x_i - \mu}{\hat\sigma} = 
\frac{1}{\mu^2\hat\tau}\sum_{j=1}^m\frac{y_j - 1/\mu}{\hat\tau} = \frac{m}{\mu^2\hat\tau^2}\left(\bar y - 1/\mu\right).$$

The equation in $\mu$, whose solutions must include the estimate $\hat\mu$, is of fourth degree, rather than linear.  Nevertheless it can be solved numerically and typically will produce a global minimum somewhere near $\bar x$ or $1/\bar y$, provided there are enough data and their variances are not too large. (The presence of negative values is not a good sign!)

(Alternatively, we might hope that the variance of $y$ decreases with $\mu$, as is often the case in measuring positive quantities.  In that case we might discover that the $y_j$ are perhaps better modeled using distributions whose variances are $\tau^2/\mu^2$ (for example).  This would turn the preceding equation back into one which is linear in $\mu$, making it straightforward to solve.  This possibility suggests **there is value in studying how the precision of the measurement process producing the $y_j$ might vary with $\mu$.**  The $x_i$ measurement process deserves a comparable study.)

**Simulations** suggest that with the conditions described in the question ($\bar x$ near $3$, $n=30$, $m=12$, and some negative values in the $y$ data), using the $y$ data actually does not improve the precision of the estimates.  The estimates are improved when the aggregate $y$ measurements are relatively more precise than the aggregate $x$ measurements; that is, when $m\tau^2 \mu^2 \gg n\sigma^2 / \mu^2$ ($\tau \ll \frac{m}{n}\sigma/\mu^2$), assuming $\mu \gt 1$.  Here is an example of that good situation, and indeed $\hat\mu$ is closer to $\mu$ than $\bar x$ is:

[image: Figure]

*The vertical solid blue lines are the true mean $\mu=3$.  The vertical solid gray lines show the means $\bar x$ and $1/\bar y$.  The vertical dashed red lines show the ML estimate $\hat\mu$.  The horizontal dashed red line in the Profile Likelihood plot shows an upper $95\%$ confidence limit for $\Lambda$: values of $\mu$ for which the graph of $\Lambda$ lie below this limit form a two-sided $95\%$ confidence interval for $\mu$.  In this example that interval does not include the true value of $\mu$.  However--as you can check--re-running this example with different randomly-generated data will produce intervals that include the true value $95\%$ of the time.*

FWIW, applying this procedure to the data (as given in a comment to another answer, interpreting the 12 values of "first var" to be $x$ and the 30 values of "second var" to be $y$) yields $\hat\mu = 1.79$, with a $95\%$ confidence interval approximately $[1.2,2.5]$.  The data reflect a large amount of measurement error: $\hat\sigma=1.85$ and $\hat\tau=1.40$.  Here is a summary of the data and the fit:

[image: Figure 2]

**NB** The dashed horizontal red line in the right-hand plot is too high: it should be located around $23.5$.

Here is the `R` code to compute $\hat\mu, \hat\sigma, \hat\tau$, and to conduct such simulations.

```r
#
# Negative log (partial) likelihood.
#
lambda <- function(mu, sigma2, tau2, x, y) {
  (sum((x - mu)^2)/sigma2 + sum((y - 1/mu)^2)/tau2)/2
}
#
# Maximum likelihood estimation.
#
mle <- function(x, y) {
  sigma.hat <- mean((x-mean(x))^2)
  tau.hat <- mean((y-mean(y))^2)
  fit <- optimize(lambda, c(min(1/max(y), min(x)), max(x, 1/min(y))),
                  sigma2=sigma.hat, tau2=tau.hat, x=x, y=y)
  list(mu.hat=fit$minimum, sigma.hat=sigma.hat, tau.hat=tau.hat, 
       Lambda=fit$objective)
}
#
# Create sample data.
#
set.seed(17)
n <- 30; m <- 12
mu <- 3
sigma <- 1/2
tau <- 0.5 * (m/n) * sigma / mu^2
x <- rnorm(n, mu, sigma)
y <- rnorm(m, 1/mu, tau)
#
# Find the solution.
#
fit <- mle(x, y)
#
# Plot the data and profile log likelihood
#
se <- sd(x) / sqrt(n)
i <- seq(fit$mu.hat-3*se, fit$mu.hat+3*se, length.out=101)
z <- sapply(i, function(j) lambda(j, fit$sigma.hat, fit$tau.hat, x, y))
markup <- function(z) {
  abline(v = mu, col="Blue", lwd=2)
  if(!missing(z)) abline(v = z, col="Gray", lwd=2)
  abline(v = fit$mu.hat, lwd=2, col="Red", lty=3) #$
}
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
hist(x, freq=FALSE); markup(mean(x))
hist(1/y, freq=FALSE); markup(1/mean(y))
plot(i, z, type="l", xlab="mu", ylab="Lambda", main="Profile Likelihood")
abline(v = mu, col="Blue", lwd=2)
abline(h = fit$Lambda + qchisq(0.95, 1)/2, lty=3, lwd=2, col="Red")
```

Answer (score 1):

I want to complete whuber answer (very nice as always) with some distribution free considerations.

I denote $E(Z) = m$ and $\text{Var}(Z) = \sigma^2$ by $Z\sim (m, \sigma^2)$.

First, a small lemma (using Delta method) : if $Z \sim \left({1\over \mu}, \sigma^2\right)$, then approximately ${1\over Z} \sim \left( \mu + \mu^3 \sigma^2, \mu^2\sigma^2\right)$. This comes readily from the first and second order approximations
$$\begin{aligned}
{1\over Y} = {1\over {1\over \mu} + Y - {1\over \mu}} &\simeq \mu - \mu^2 \left(Y-{1\over\mu}\right)\\
&\simeq \mu - \mu^2 \left(Y-{1\over\mu}\right)+\mu^3\left(Y-{1\over\mu}\right)^2.
\end{aligned}$$
Note that you need to assume that the support of the law is in $\mathbb R^{>0}$ or in $\mathbb R^{<0}$ for this to make sense.

Now assume $Y_1, \dots, Y_m$ are independent $~\sim\left({1\over \mu},\sigma^2\right)$. There are two natural ways to find an estimate of $\mu$, and from the above lemma we can find approximations of their expected value and variance:

$$\begin{aligned}
{1\over m} \left( {1\over Y_1} + \cdots +  {1\over Y_m} \right) &\sim \left( \mu + \mu^3 \sigma^2, {1\over m}\mu^2\sigma^2 \right) \\
{m \over Y_1 + \cdots + Y_m} &\sim \left( \mu + {1\over m} \mu^3 \sigma^2, {1\over m}\mu^2\sigma^2 \right) 
\end{aligned}$$

The second one a bias in $1 \over m$, where as the first has constant bias. This is somehow intuitive, but I think this was worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have two sets of data: $x_i$ and $y_j$. We know that $\frac{1}{y_j}=x_j$ from theory or the previous research. I think the best estimate of the average $\bar x$ is the following: 
$$\bar x=\frac{\sum_{n_x}x_i+\sum_{n_y}\frac{1}{y_j}}{n_x+n_y}$$

Let's see if it's biased: 
$$E[\bar x - \mu]=\frac{\sum_{n_x}(E[x_i]-\mu)+\sum_{n_y}(E[\frac{1}{y_j}]-\mu)}{n_x+n_y}=0$$

This is because $$E[\frac{1}{y_j}]=E[x_j]=\mu$$
Note, that $E[y]\ne\frac{1}{\mu}$

If you want to compare the ratios, then proceed in a similar fashion:

$$\mu_x=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n_x}x_i}{n_x}$$ and 
$$\mu_y=\frac{\sum_{j=1}^{n_y}\frac{1}{y_j}}{n_x}$$

the same goes for standard deviations and the usual t-test ANOVA: use $\frac{1}{y_j}$ wherever you use used $x_i$. The key here is not to work on aggregates, such as $E[y_j]$, because they're not convertible easily into $\frac{1}{E[x]}$ due to Jensen inequality.

UPDATE
Here's analogy from physics. Let's say you're measuring the resistance. You have Ohm-meter, which measures it directly and shows 10 Ohm.

Now, you measure it with a Ampere-meter by connecting the resistor to the DC power supply which produces 10 Volt. Ohm's Law: $R=\frac{V}{I}$. You read two measurements:  1.1 A and 1.2 A.

I'm suggesting you compare 10 $\Omega$ with $\frac{\frac{10}{1.1}+\frac{10}{1.2}}{2}=8.7 \Omega$

UPDATE2:
Based on OP's comments, it seems the model is as follows:
$$x_i=z_i+e_i$$
$$y_j=\frac{1}{z_j}+u_j$$
Here, $z$ is what we want to measure, while $x$ and $y$ are what we actually measure, and $e,u$ are errors, which are quite large.

If you go with combining $E[x]$ and $\frac{1}{E[y]}$, then you'll have to deal with the bias $\frac{1}{E[y]}-E[z]$.

I think in this case it is important to understand the errors, especially $u_j$. If we knew something about the distribution, we could correct for bias.

Comment: This answer is confusing. It is not the case that $E[1/y_j] = x_j$, as Jensen's inequality immediately shows. The whole point of the question is that $y_j$ and $x_j$ are measurements *with error*. In fact, there is not even a pairing of the $y_j$ and $x_i$: they are two (perhaps independent) datasets.

Comment: @whuber, OP wrote that $x_i$ is 30 measurements and $y_j$ is 12 measurements. OP computed *means* $\bar x$ and $\bar y$. OP stated that underlying physics suggests that $\frac{1}{y_j}$ should correspond to $x$ somehow. I'm suggesting not to average $\bar y$, but to get an average of $\frac{1}{y_j}$ directly.

Comment: Starting at "$1/y_j = x_j$", which does not match anything you have written so far (because it implies that somehow the two datasets have been paired), your interpretation of the question and your assumptions become progressively less clear.

Comment: @whuber, read my update in the post. No, I'm not assuming any pairing. The analogy is to measure the resistance in Ohms directly vs. in Amperes (given constant voltage). So, $\frac{10 V}{y A}\sim x\Omega$

Comment: I am not criticizing your assumptions (because I can't figure them out).  I am only pointing out that what you are writing is inconsistent with the information in the question and likely is not saying what you think it is.  Given that the question itself is inherently ambiguous, it is difficult to see how you can justify any answer at this time unless you are quite explicit and clear about what you think the data are and what you believe the question to be.

Comment: Thank you both. Aksakal, your analogy of electrical measurements is spot-on. The problem that I have, though, is that the measurements are very noisy. So some of them show up negative, or close to 0 which creates a whole host of issues when using 1/x. So what I did is take the median and interquartile range of each variable, and that gets me reasonable results for each variable's "center of gravity" and dispersion, as I gave in the example. (not exactly mean and SD - but for my purposes - OK) The problem is in combining these medians.

Comment: How about inverting X variable? Is it as noisy?

Comment: Both variables are noisy...

Comment: Maybe you have to deal with noise first. With stats you can do only so much.  Can you show the data?

Comment: first var [0] 2.187
[1] -1.356
[2] 1.6815
[3] 1.07
[4] 1.2885
[5] 3.1345
[6] -0.1245
[7] 2.672
[8] 2.1955
[9] 1.2
[10] 3.9365
[11] 2.145
[12] 6.7495
 
second var 
[0] 0.1005
[1] -0.062
[2] 0.02775
[3] 0.03175
[4] 0.1525
[5] 0.40325
[6] 0.408
[7] 0.37425
[8] 0.31525
[9] 0.18475
[10] 0.2125
[11] 0.2985
[12] 0.249166667
[13] 0.06375
[14] 0.16525
[15] 0.3025
[16] 0.2575
[17] 0.1195
[18] 0.017
[19] 0.53225
[20] 0.48125
[21] 0.3005
[22] 0.4815
[23] 0.182333333
[24] 0.376
[25] -0.0425
[26] 0.24775
[27] 0.2635
[28] 0.04025

Comment: @jobxyz1, Ok, the good thing is that it doesn't look like Gaussian, otyherwise you'd be in trouble, see [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/646428/mean-and-variance-of-reciprocal-normal-distribution), you wouldn't be able to invert the reading of Y meaningfully. Do you have any intuition about the nature of errors in Y? Its distribution or maybe the source?